# Did I accidently sync my iPhone with a work computer? What have I shared?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud

So I have a work computer (a Dell laptop) and a personal iPhone. I’ve used this laptop to charge my iPhone and when doing so, I’ve allowed access when the prompt asks “Trust this computer?”.

Did I inadvertently allow syncing my iPhone with this laptop and share my web browsing history from my iPhone?

I don’t see it on my laptop’s internet history nor any of my phones images or contacts in my laptop, but my anxiety riddled self would like to be sure. (I was also logged into a google account on my laptop but not on my iPhone).

My phone and my laptop was on my home wifi while running a VPN.

When I go to my phones settings and click devices, I see that my work laptop is listed as one of the devices. I have never signed on to my iTunes account on work dell laptop.

Any answers is appreciated. I turn in my work laptop the first week of next month. Also under my iCloud settings, safari is turned off.

Comment: Does your work laptop have iTunes installed? If no, then no syncing would have happened as iTunes is required to sync your iPhone with Windows. If it has iTunes, then you need to open iTunes and check if anything has been copied.

Comment: You can (and should) also ["untrust" your dell laptop](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/104263). Note that even if you "untrust" a device, it can still charge your iPhone when connected to it.

Answer (score 2):

Approving a "Trust this computer" request enables basic communication between the phone and a computer, it doesn't transfer data per se. Basically it ensures that others can't just take your phone, connect it to their computer and transfer all your data without you knowing.

With Windows you will probably see your phone somewhere in Explorer afterwards, mainly the photos should be accessible. But you still would need to copy them to your Computer,